# How can I iterate through the array and start rotating the cubes from the array at random intervals?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float xAngle, yAngle, zAngle;
    public GameObject[] objectsToRotate;

    private bool isRotating = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(isRotating == true)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
            {
                objectsToRotate[i].transform.Rotate(xAngle, yAngle, zAngle);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        isRotating = true;
    }
}
```

For example the first object should start rotating at once.
The second one after 0.3f seconds and the third one after 1 second.
Each object should start rotating at another random time.

All of them should finish after rotating 360 degrees.

Before that I used a Coroutine to rotate a single object.

```
private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (isRotating == false)
            StartCoroutine(Rotate(5));
    }

    IEnumerator Rotate(float duration)
    {
        Quaternion startRot = transform.rotation;
        float t = 0.0f;
        while (t < duration)
        {
            isRotating = true;
            t += Time.deltaTime;

            transform.rotation = startRot * Quaternion.AngleAxis(t / duration * 360f, Vector3.up);

            yield return null;
        }
        transform.rotation = startRot;

        isRotating = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also can use your coroutine. Your code might be something like that:

```
public Transform[] objectsToRotate;

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    foreach (var objectTransform in objectsToRotate)
    {
        float delay = Random.Range(0.0f, 5.0f);
        float duration = 2.0f;
        StartCoroutine(Rotate(objectTransform, duration, delay));
    }
}

IEnumerator Rotate(Transform objectTransform, float duration, float delay)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    Quaternion startRot = objectTransform.rotation;
    float t = 0.0f;
    while (t < duration)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime;

        objectTransform.rotation = startRot * Quaternion.AngleAxis(t / duration * 360f, Vector3.up);
        yield return true;
    }
    objectTransform.rotation = startRot;
}
```

Delay is simple random but you can adjust it if you want.